# How to overlay something on a Google map, without blocking the mouse interaction?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to draw something on a google map. So I though to put a canvas over the map, and draw stuff, just that this is blocking the interaction with the map. How can I draw something but leave the rest of the map interactive? Relevant code snippets:

Styles:

```
<style>
#myCanvas {
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
}
#canvas-wrap {
    position:relative;
} /* Make this a positioned parent */
#map_canvas {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
</style>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadMap() {
  var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326);
  var mapOptions = {center: fenway, zoom: 14, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function drawLine(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(100, 100);
  context.lineTo(400, 400);
  context.lineWidth = 9;
  context.stroke();
};

function init(){
  loadMap();
  drawLine();
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="canvas-wrap">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600px" height="600px"></canvas>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 600px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ocelot20's answer works as long as your overlays don't require user interaction. If they do, you need to use Google's provided Polygon (etc) classes.

Forwarding events *might* work, but you're completely at the mercy of Google not changing some minor detail of the event mechanism. And, not insignificantly, you'll have to forward events in both directions: from Google's map layer to your canvas, and from transparent parts of your canvas to Google's map layer.

Ie. use a Polygon ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `pointer-events' CSS attribute is what you're looking for:

```
#map_canvas {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index: -1;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

This will basically make the canvas transparent to mouse events.

Edit - Apparently this only applies to certain browsers. This is a more complicated but cross-browser compatible method:

[Forwarding Mouse Events Through Layers](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/)